# How can I translate Ubercart Checkout panes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

How can I translate Ubercart Checkout panes ?

I was wondering if they can automatically translated into another language (german). I know i18n module, but I was wondering how to use it together with Ubercart checkout.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the translation for your language at:
http://localize.drupal.org/translate/projects/ubercart

Then, from your translate interface import screen in Drupal, import this file.

German seems to be pretty well translated, but there are still strings missing.
you can manually translate these using the translate interface search string screen or with the l10n_client helper module.

For Drupal 7, the preffered way is to contribute back as described here:
http://localize.drupal.org/node/2024